verify if a token is not a honeypot
automatically, via code, what is the best way to verify if a token is a honeypot or not.
I tried:

contract verified or not
some external APIs (not very reliable)
lint the contract


Currently it is not possible to reliable detect honeypot tokens, or other scam tokens, on Ethereum, as discussed here. Any statistical analysis about token features and distributions is quite easy to game and poor bastards who write "sniping bots" will end up donating their money to scammers. Any service that claims to be honeypot detector is going to have a high failure rate, and should not be fully trusted.
